# Bootstrap Navbar-collaps not opening on click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I am trying to use bootstrap Navbar-collaps menu for my Mobile.site.master page but it seems to be having problems, the button is where I want it its just on click the menu doesn't actually open and I don't know why any help would be amazing. The code is posted below if you need anything else please let me know.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BRAND</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">Fixed Link</a>
                      </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                     <li><a href="#">L1</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#">L2</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an ID in your menu div `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="MenuID">` and call it in your button `data-target="#MenuID"`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MenuID" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="MenuID">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">L1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">L2</a></li>

      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Fixed Link</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

You can see the result here [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/PortarWi2F)

Comment: than you must have some files that are missing ...you must have jQuery.js bootstrap.js bootstrap.css

Comment: @Chiller Hey can you explain your Answer lol
tji lel bher bennouna

Comment: what did u not understand .. wach belemo khalini nekhchan chwia oumba3d nrouh :p

Answer (score 0):

one change in your code you forget href  `"` second link

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                     <li><a href="#">L1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">L2</a></li>
                </ul>
```

your code is working now

may be you included this file ?

```
bootstrap.css
jquery library
bootstrap.js
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k60f4x3c/

Comment: how would I check if those files are included ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstate a backup of my project and while using Github it deleted one of the JS files needed to make the dropdown work, there wasn't actually an error in my code just some of it had gone missing.